# Check if username contains curse words

Tags: javascript, php

I have a user register system where users can change their username to something like "username123" except I would like to filter those usernames from hate and harassment what would be the best way to do this?

I was thinking of making a new table in phpmyadmin with specific words and compare those with the _post username in php, but maybe their is a better / faster way to do this? I do have a .txt file with the specific words.

Comment: Use a hashed structure for fast lookup.  But you're probably engaging in a losing battle.  Oh, and you may or may not need to worry about the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: If you want to filter swear words, you'd rather use a plugin to do so otherwise it will be a very tedious job. And I don't recommend storing swear words in a database when you can use a plugin as there are so many swear words and it will be an extra load on the db if saved.

Comment: You can check around github for some. I saw a few js and php plugins.